# Create a record for each column AND each row SSIS

Tags: database, csv, ssis, pivot, ssis-2008

I'm builiding a SSIS-package that will update/create records in a database based on survey answers. 
What I have is a file looking kinda like this:

```
ID;Answer1;Answer2;Answer3
123;yes;no;no
1234;no;no;no
```

No what I want to do is create a record PER answer! So what I want to import is basically:

```
ID;Answertype;answer
123;Answer1;yes
123;Answer2;no
123;Answer3;no
1234;Answer1;no
1234;Answer2;no
1234;Answer3;no
```

How do I do that?
sidenote: I have an "old" version of Visual Studio (2008).

Answer (score 0):

Use the UNPIVOT Transformation.